# Trying to search through a directory of folders WinError 2

Tags: python-3.x, csv

I'm trying to search and change the name of files in directory of 141 folders. Everything is working but I am getting this error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the specified file: 'CU14.csv' -> 'CU11.csv'
```

Here is the code I'm working with:

```
with open('C:/Users/Desktop/Excels/Libro2.csv') as f1:
reader = csv.reader(f1)
Matrixf1 = list(reader)

i1=0
while i1 < 140:
    path1 = os.listdir(str(Matrixf1[i1][0]))

    for fileName in path1:
        if 'CU14' in fileName:
            os.rename(fileName, fileName.replace("CU14", "CU11"))
```